# Client Side Only standalone Smtp Client/relay, for sending mails directly

Tags: smtp, telnet, client-side-scripting, web-client

Usually, when you send an e-mail (with Thunderbird or Outlook), you don't send it directly.
example: I have a gmail address and I want to send an e-mail to a myopera address. The process will be:

user->gmail server(gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com)->myopera server(in1.smtp.messagingengine.com)->final user who'll download it's email with pop/imap.

One of the inconvenient is the size: Imagine you have attachment of 50Mb: the limit of myopera is 60MB; but the limit of gmail is 25MB,So the mail will be refused whereas it would be accepted if it was send directly to myopera.

But I saw with [telnet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia%3aOracle/semaine_43_2013#Envoyer_un_SMS_par_e-mail) that, it is possible to send mail directly with SMTP commands.

I want to write a client-side Only web application which would convert a mail in a set of SMTP commands for sending it. I should be very basic and not support encryption

***I don't know how to create a TCP connection from a client, so, here's my questions: Does a library already exist? If not, what I should use? I've read about the existence of WebSockets but that Ajax would be more universal.***

Also, most of the actuals implementations of WebSocket I saw, don't work in my latests versions of web browser despite the fact they 'support it'. There's also the raw Socket API from the W3c (I've no idea of the web browsers which actually support it).
**So, I would like to not avoid statements telling it is impossible to create near raw TCP/UDP session. Since it is possible, I can't imagine nobody created a kind of library for dealing with protocols**

Comment: this sounds like a very bad route to take, you are reinventing the wheel, your solution will be platform/browser specific and will probably require elevated privileges.

Comment: @NickolaiNielsen No,Web standards aren't platform specific.There is also a security hole present in latest browsers which make there's no need for elevated privileges: On windows it is just required that the browser exist in `add/remove program`.Otherwise, there's a pop-up windows asking for network privileges which can be refused  and let the browser then running.See also this [example](http://www.davidmclifton.com/2011/07/22/simple-telnet-server-in-node-js/):I want a more generic way which could work without node.js.I'm think something already exist and I wouldn't have to start from scratch.

Comment: node.js is a executable running outside the browser, so it has access to raw TCP sockets. It would not / should not have that access inside the browser unless you use a exploit or breaks the sandbox in some way.

Comment: @NickolaiNielsen I've seen that web browser can open TCP ports or even listen for incoming connections without any privilege (at the only condition they are locally installed on windows/OSX). One of the example was Opera unite. jSocket socketjs are implementation which do that but use third party plug-ins. I recognize, this the same as implementing arbitrary protocols with web language. their is navigator.registerProtocolHandler(), but I don't see any way to use the produced output in scripts. (Sorry, I was thinking modern browser made opening telnet sessions easy)

Comment: I've found [this](http://www.w3.org/2012/sysapps/raw-sockets/ "Raw Socket API")

Answer (score 1):

You should take an alternative route.

If i had that issue i would still use a server side component of some sort, and just have the server contact to receiving mail server directly.

Given the email: "someuser@somedomain.tld" you could do a DNS MX record lookup on "somedomain.tld" and find the receiving mail server say "mail.somedomain.tld", then you could tell your mail send component to send the email directly to "mail.somedomain.tld", that way you would have an immediate feedback on whatever the mail went through or not.

Comment: No, I just want it to be client-side only for fun. I want to do this the same way a tenet script would. this is mainly to get an experience in working with TCP sockets. I hope to implement a web server that would work in a web browser, but lets begin with simpler. Moreover, I've chosen a µcontroller for running the server.

Comment: you can't get raw TCP sockets in a browser, btw why do you ask here when it is a "fun" project, go google and learn instead!

Comment: what is the purpose? writing malware to send spam?

Comment: No, Simply offer a way to send e-mail without needing to trust an intermediate server, or installing a third party app. It would be a graphical e-mail(SMTP) client which could run locally if you download the files from the server. It would also help to bypass certain size limit as I've explained in my question.

Comment: Also, I already had the idea of the DNS request, but establishing a session is not as simple as you think: The user may chose to use the SMTP server IP address (wich can be v4 or v6) in the case it don't have a public DNS record. Many servers use IP white list for authorising connection. There's also many kind of errors messages which can append at any time in the session (The server has no obligation to return a 250 response at any time).

Comment: if you are doing the DNS lookup, the user don't need to enter a SMTP server.

Comment: What I'm meaning Is that I'm trying to find some libraries to create an SMTP client which would directly (and thus could communicate with LAN only servers). In regular graphical client you can use the form of user@ip_address instead of user@host if the mail server don't have any DNS record.

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C you may use https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage

By looking at the source you see how SMTP works.

Comment: EHLO :) Thank you, but I know perfectly how smtp work. I often send e-mails with with openssl for starttls. When I am under XP, I often use `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`. Moreover, I asked for web-language, I don't want anything on the server side except the ftp server.